# Sometimes can't able to write in terminal: Debian 9.5

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

Not sure what could be the reason (I am using debian 9.5) but sometime when I try to run any command in terminal it seems like none of the keys work except `ctrl+c`

And I specifically facing this error while try to run JavaScropt code.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: What keys are you typing, and when? As you type the `node...` command, or during the `node ...` execution, or after?

Comment: Have you at that point tried to do a tab completion in a big directory? Does it help if you turn programmable completions off in `bash` with `complete -r`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time you encounter this problem, try pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>.

If that fixes the problem, you're probably accidentally pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> - the ["pause transmission" character of XON/XOFF software flow control.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control)

If you want to disable the XON/XOFF functionality (to get rid of this problem more permanently), add something like this to your `~/.bashrc` or equivalent:

```
if tty -s; then
    stty -ixon
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried those commands, it appears like it could be the issue of ctrl+s as I press is many times :)